# Change Tier on Azcopy

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I need to download multiple archived files from Azure Storage Account StorageV2 (general purpose v2), but it seems that I need first to rehydrate them from archive to cold or hot tier first.

Is there a way in AzCopy (I'm using AzCopy V10.10.0) to change the tier of a file which is already uploaded?

I really like AzCopy as it's easy to use with the SAS token.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access data that is stored on the archive tier, without rehydrating it first.

You can use powershell to copy from the archive tier to hot tier storage. You will then be able to copy with AzCopy.

```
#Initialize the following with your resource group, storage account, container, and blob names
$rgName = ""
$accountName = ""
$srcContainerName = ""
$destContainerName = ""
$srcBlobName = ""
$destBlobName = ""

#Select the storage account and get the context
$storageAccount =Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $accountName
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

#Copy source blob to a new destination blob with access tier hot using standard rehydrate priority
Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -SrcContainer $srcContainerName -SrcBlob $srcBlobName -DestContainer $destContainerName -DestBlob $destBlobName -StandardBlobTier Hot -RehydratePriority Standard -Context $ctx
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-rehydration?tabs=azure-powershell#quickstart-scenarios

Comment: Why would you want to copy the archived blob to a new blob when you can simply change the access tier of a blob from `Archive` to `Hot` or `Cool` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-tier.

Comment: @GauravMantri you have a point. It is just if you wanted to keep all blobs in the same container in the same tier

Comment: @GauravMantri, actually also the cost. You need to pay for a minimum of 180 days in archive. if you have had the blob i archive for 10 days and then change it to hot, then you must pay for the remaining 170 days, plus start paying for the hot tier. If you copy it and then delete it once it is used, then the extra cost is minimum.

Comment: @GauravMantri PS congratulations on reaching 100 000 points

Comment: Thank you @ShirazBhaiji, your feedback is very useful. Also I like your strategy on saving costs.